# When am I notified of edits on my posts?

Tags: support, edits, notifications

I know that I'm always notified of suggested edits on my post, I also remember being notified of an edit on my answer by a 2ker and other times, but I don't know which are the triggers of the later. Other than suggested edits, what are the conditions to be notified of edits made by people with editing privileges?

Comment: AFAIK you always get notified of edits made to your posts.

Comment: @JonClements yet I wasn't notified of M. A. R. edit... :(

Comment: @animuson I don't get notifications if one of you guys close the question as duplicate!